# followed-by operator not possible with tsvector constructed from jsonb due to gaps in word numbering index

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-15

Input:

`select to_tsvector('simple', '["one","two","three"]'::jsonb)`

returns

`'one':1 'three':5 'two':3`

Expected:

`'one':1 'three':3 'two':2`

Which words have index 2 and 4? Is this a bug? How do I use it in a valid way?

With those gaps in the index numbering any search using a followed-by operator (ex: `'one' <-> 'zwo'`) is doomed to fail.

How I can repair that using immutable **existing** functions? The jsonb originates from a call to `jsonb_path_query_array()` which could be changed to `jsonb_path_query()` but I have no clue how to consolidate a set of jsonb values into a single tsvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that a phrase query across multiple JSON array elements is, er, weird.

You could work around that by casting the JSON to `text`:

```
select to_tsvector('simple', '["one","two","three"]'::jsonb::text);

        to_tsvector        
═══════════════════════════
 'one':1 'three':3 'two':2
(1 row)
```

That type cast is `IMMUTABLE`.

Comment: I never had an interest in json elements, all I wanted was a space delimited text-blob out of an existing large jsonb document by applying `jsonb_path_query_array("BigJson", '$.Pages[*].TextBlocks[*].Lines[*].Words[*].Text')` - just to feed it into `to_tsvector`.